# Select row by max value in group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataframe which was created via a `df.pivot`:

```
type                             start  end
F_Type         to_date                     
A              20150908143000    345    316
B              20150908140300    NaN    480
               20150908140600    NaN    120
               20150908143000  10743   8803
C              20150908140100    NaN   1715
               20150908140200    NaN   1062
               20150908141000    NaN    145
               20150908141500    418    NaN
               20150908141800    NaN    450
               20150908142900   1973   1499
               20150908143000  19522  16659
D              20150908143000    433     65
E              20150908143000   7290   7375
F              20150908143000      0      0
G              20150908143000   1796    340
```

I would like to filter and return a single row for each 'F_TYPE' only returning the row with the maximum 'to_date'. I would like to return the following dataframe:

```
type                             start  end
F_Type         to_date                     
A              20150908143000    345    316
B              20150908143000  10743   8803
C              20150908143000  19522  16659
D              20150908143000    433     65
E              20150908143000   7290   7375
F              20150908143000      0      0
G              20150908143000   1796    340
```

Comment: Is `F_Type` a column or your index? I think `df.groupby('F_Type').max()` should work or `df.groupby(df.index).max()`, actually I think `df.max(level=0)` should work

Answer (score 97, accepted):

A standard approach is to use `groupby(keys)[column].idxmax()`.
However, to select the desired rows using [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) you need `idxmax` to return unique index values. One way to obtain a unique index is to call `reset_index`.

Once you obtain the index values from `groupby(keys)[column].idxmax()` you can then select the entire row using `df.loc`:

```
In [20]: df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby(['F_Type'])['to_date'].idxmax()]
Out[20]: 
                       start    end
F_Type to_date                     
A      20150908143000    345    316
B      20150908143000  10743   8803
C      20150908143000  19522  16659
D      20150908143000    433     65
E      20150908143000   7290   7375
F      20150908143000      0      0
G      20150908143000   1796    340
```

Note: `idxmax` returns index *labels*, not necessarily ordinals. After using `reset_index` the index labels happen to also be ordinals, but since `idxmax` is returning labels (not ordinals) it is better to *always* use `idxmax` in conjunction with `df.loc`, not `df.iloc` (as I originally did in this post.)

Comment: This answer uses an approach that appears to now deprecated with this error message: "KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike" "

Answer (score 16):

The other ways to do that are as follow:

1. If you want only one max row per group.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda group: group.nlargest(1, columns='to_date'))
    .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
)
```

2. If you want to get all rows that are equal to max per group.

```py
(
    df
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda group: group.loc[group['to_date'] == group['to_date'].max()])
    .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

A much more concise solution is to sort the index and call `groupby.tail`.

```py
new_df = df.sort_index().groupby(level='F_Type').tail(1)
```

Note that in the OP, `F_Type` and `to_date` are indices. If they were columns, use `sort_values` instead and call `groupby.tail`:

```py
new_df = df.sort_values(['F_Type', 'to_date']).groupby('F_Type').tail(1)
```

[image: result]