# How to remove and filter repeated entries in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I have a dataframe with the following 3 columns

```
  ID       Department      Number
---------------------------------
2324              Art           4
2324             Math           1
2324              Art           3
2400          Science           2
2593             Tech           5
2593             Math           1
```

I'm trying to filter first by ID, then by Number. As you can see, some IDs repeat. I want to first find the IDs that repeat, then choose the highest corresponding Number.

For instance, as you can see the ID 2324 repeats 3 times. (4, 1, 3) are the Numbers that correspond with each entry of 2324. Since 4 is the bigger number, I choose the entry with 4. I want to filter the dataframe to get this output:

```
   ID       Department      Number
---------------------------------
2324              Art           4
2400          Science           2
2593             Tech           5
```

This is my code so far :

```
for previous, current in zip(df['ID'], df['ID'][1:]):
   for i, j in zip(df['Number'], df['Number'][1:]):
     if previous == current:
        if j> i:
```

However, I don't know what I should add next to correctly `print(previous, j)`.
If I add `print(previous, j)` to the nested loop, I get repeated entries.
For instance, if my code was

```
for previous, current in zip(df['ID'], df['ID'][1:]):
   for i, j in zip(df['Number'], df['Number'][1:]):
     if previous == current:
        if j> i:
          print(previous, j)
```

it outputs

```
2324       4
2324       4
2324       4
2324       4
2324       4
2324       4        
2593       5   
2593       5
2593       5   
2593       5
```

I want it to output:

```
2324       4     
2593       5
```

I also want it to include the ID that was not repeated, so `2400  2` in this case.
Additionally, I don't know how to append the correct Department name to the nested loop.

Thank you to anyone who took the time to read this and help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This one is probably the exact solution you are looking for [Python Pandas Dataframe select row by max value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459325/python-pandas-dataframe-select-row-by-max-value-in-group)

Comment: You don't need loop to achieve what you want, you can first sort the values of your Number column and then use the drop_duplciates, like this: 
`df.sort_values(by=['num'], ascending=False)` followed by `df.drop_duplicates("id", inplace=True)`, by default, the drop_duplicates will keep the first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Number'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: It is dupe `loc + groupby + idxmax`

Comment: @jezrael wikied

Comment: @U12-Forward actually, one more question, suppose the 'Department' isn't first? How do I factor that in?

Comment: @shorttriptomars Maybe `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()`

Comment: This is wrong. Worked only since each group's max is in the first row...

Comment: @U12-Forward I'm sorry that doesn't work. It still doesn't factor in if the corresponding  Dept is not listed first

Comment: @shorttriptomars Could you please explain again?

Comment: @U12-Forward in the dataframe, say  instead of `(Tech   5),  (Math    1)` it's listed as `(Tech   1),  (Math   5)` . The code you provided would still print Tech for Department, instead of changing it to Math

Comment: @shorttriptomars Than use `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()`

Comment: @U12-Forward I'm sorry that doesn't work.

Comment: @shorttriptomars - You need `idxmax` for corresponding row, check dupe for correct answer.

Comment: @jezrael can you please explain how? when I add '`idmax` I get the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'idmax'`

Comment: @shorttriptomars - `df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Number'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @shorttriptomars - Convert `Number` to numeric.