# Pandas loop for checking the most recent data with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops

This question shouldn't be closed as I have already checked this question [Select row by max value in group in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459325/select-row-by-max-value-in-group-in-a-pandas-dataframe) Here it doesn't go back to check the empty values and doesnt have the condition to check the value upto 5 years. And I have already applied upto the answer explained in this question. My question is few more conditions than the attached duplicate question.

Following is the example datasets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
data=[['Afghanistan','2015','5.1'],
  ['Afghanistan','2016','6.1'],
  ['Djibouti','2021',''],
  ['Djibouti','2020',''],
  ['Djibouti','2019','30'],
  ['Egypt','2019',''],
  ['Egypt','2018',''],
  ['Egypt','2015','37'],
  ['Bahrain','2020','32'],
  ['Bahrain','2021','']],
columns=['Country', 'Reference Year', 'value'])
```

I am trying to get the most recent data using the following codes.

```
most_recent = df1[df1.groupby('Country')['Reference Year'].transform('max') == df1['Reference Year']]
most_recent['Reference Year'] = 'Most recent data'
```

However, it only checks the data with the highest year which meets one condition and I have more conditions to check. For example, if the highest year has empty data, it has to go back to one year behind and check and get the values. My top year is 2021 and hence it can go upto years behind to look for the latest data which is 2016 and stop there. If there are no values until 2016, then only it should give empty value. Please help!

Here my expected output is :

```
Afghanistan Most recent data 6.1
Djibouti    Most recent data 30
Egypt       Most recent data
Bahrain     Most recent data 32
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a mask to identify the rows with unwanted values and sort them in the desired priority order before running [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html):

```
df['Reference Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Reference Year'], errors='coerce')

(df.assign(m=df['Reference Year'].ge(df['Reference Year'].max()-5)
                                     & df['value'].ne(''))
   .sort_values(by=['Country', 'm', 'Reference Year'])
   .groupby('Country', as_index=False).last()[['Country', 'value']]
)
```

Output:

```
       Country value
0  Afghanistan   6.1
1      Bahrain    32
2     Djibouti    30
3        Egypt
```

Intermediate before `groupby.last`:

```
       Country  Reference Year value      m
0  Afghanistan            2015   5.1  False
1  Afghanistan            2016   6.1   True
9      Bahrain            2021        False
8      Bahrain            2020    32   True
3     Djibouti            2020        False
2     Djibouti            2021        False
4     Djibouti            2019    30   True
7        Egypt            2015    37  False
6        Egypt            2018        False
5        Egypt            2019        False
```

Alternatively, using a custom function:

```
df['Reference Year'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Reference Year'], errors='coerce')

threshold = df['Reference Year'].max()-5

def get_latest(g, threshold):
    m1 = g['Reference Year'].ge(threshold)
    m2 = g['value'].ne('')
    tmp = g.loc[m1&m2, 'Reference Year']
    if tmp.empty:
        return ''
    else:
        return g.loc[tmp.idxmax(), 'value']

out = df.groupby('Country').apply(get_latest, threshold)
```

Comment: It works in most cases. I would say 80 percent cases, It works. But sometimes, it doesnt work and I couldnt find out the specific type of cases. For example, Tunisia 2020 nan
Tunisia 2019 24.3
Tunisia 2018 24
Tunisia 2017 nan
Tunisia 2016 nan
Tunisia 2015 nan
Tunisia 2014 nan
Tunisia 2013 21.8
Tunisia 2012 nan
Tunisia 2011 21.8
Tunisia 2010 nan
Tunisia Most recent data nan    is the answer instead of choosing 24.3 for 2019 as most recent data

Comment: Please edit your question with such examples in a reproducible format.

Comment: I tried this with several data sets and I found for the cases like Djibouti and Bahrain here where the greatest year is empty and it has to go back and check for the next latest year, it shows the most recent is usually nan. However when I check specifically creating those particular data sets as an example for a separate dataframe, it works. Do you think I need to change something for that? I am using the 1st solution not the custom function.

Comment: As requested above, please provide a [mre] of such cases, it's much more explicit to understand your issue.